# Avoiding Infinite Loops While Traversing Children Controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I'm writing a simple extension method to perform an action on a control and all of its children, and I'm wondering if I have to worry about running into the same control twice.

Safe:

```
public static void Traverse(this Control control, Action<Control> action)
{
    Traverse(control, action, new HashSet<control>());
}

private static void Traverse(this Control control, Action<Control> action, HashSet<Control> handled)
{
    handled.Add(control);
    foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        if (!handled.Contains(child))
            Traverse(child, action, handled);
    action.Invoke(control);
}
```

Possibly Unsafe:

```
public static void Traverse(this Control control, Action<Control> action)
{
    foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        Traverse(child, action, handled);
    action.Invoke(control);
}
```

Is the hash set necessary to keep this code safe? It needs to invoke the action on every control only once, and it can't enter an infinite loop. Is the structure of parent-child controls such that I don't need to worry about this?

Usage:

```
this.Traverse(o => o.SuspendLayout());

// Do lots of UI changes

this.Traverse(o => o.ResumeLayout());
```

---

The (possibly) comprehensive way to do this:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void Traverse(this Control control, Action<Control> action)
    {
        Traverse(control, action, TraversalMethod.DepthFirst);
    }

    public static void Traverse(this Control control, Action<Control> action, TraversalMethod method)
    {
        switch (method)
        {
            case TraversalMethod.DepthFirst:
                TraverseDepth(control, action);
                break;
            case TraversalMethod.BreadthFirst:
                TraverseBreadth(control, action);
                break;
            case TraversalMethod.ReversedDepthFirst:
                TraverseDepthReversed(control, action);
                break;
            case TraversalMethod.ReversedBreadthFirst:
                TraverseBreadthReversed(control, action);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void TraverseDepth(Control control, Action<Control> action)
    {
        Stack<Control> controls = new Stack<Control>();
        Queue<Control> queue = new Queue<Control>();

        controls.Push(control);
        while (controls.Count != 0)
        {
            control = controls.Pop();
            foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
                controls.Push(child);
            queue.Enqueue(control);
        }
        while (queue.Count != 0)
            action.Invoke(queue.Dequeue());
    }

    private static void TraverseBreadth(Control control, Action<Control> action)
    {
        Queue<Control> controls = new Queue<Control>();
        Queue<Control> queue = new Queue<Control>();

        controls.Enqueue(control);
        while (controls.Count != 0)
        {
            control = controls.Dequeue();
            foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
                controls.Enqueue(child);
            queue.Enqueue(control);
        }
        while (queue.Count != 0)
            action.Invoke(queue.Dequeue());
    }

    private static void TraverseDepthReversed(Control control, Action<Control> action)
    {
        Stack<Control> controls = new Stack<Control>();
        Stack<Control> stack = new Stack<Control>();

        controls.Push(control);
        while (controls.Count != 0)
        {
            control = controls.Pop();
            foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
                controls.Push(child);
            stack.Push(control);
        }
        while (stack.Count != 0)
            action.Invoke(stack.Pop());
    }

    private static void TraverseBreadthReversed(Control control, Action<Control> action)
    {
        Queue<Control> controls = new Queue<Control>();
        Stack<Control> stack = new Stack<Control>();

        controls.Enqueue(control);
        while (controls.Count != 0)
        {
            control = controls.Dequeue();
            foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
                controls.Enqueue(child);
            stack.Push(control);
        }
        while (stack.Count != 0)
            action.Invoke(stack.Pop());
    }
}
```

Comment: If a child had multiple parents, what would Child.Parent return? Which parent would contain the child? Where would events/keystrokes bubble up?

Comment: @Rob: All good points.  Arguably, there could be different types of containment, such as one tree for events, another for display (z-order, etc).  In this case, some controls might appear in one collection but not the other, while the rest are in both.

Comment: WPF actually does this, to some extent.  The Logical tree and the Visual Tree of "controls" is not necessarily the same in all instances...  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx

Comment: @Reed: Interesting.  If I understand correctly, it looks like it's effectively keeping a single tree but offering a filtered "logical" view of it as well as a full "visual" one.

Comment: @Steven: The "logical" tree is basically what you setup in code.  However, since everything's templated in WPF, the "visual tree", or what actually gets rendered, can be completely different.  A lot more "items" can exist in between the layers of the tree.

Comment: @Reed: Ok, that sounds like what I thought.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each child has one parent, so there's no need to worry.

Comment: ahh, but what if the starting control has no parent? I have seen this happen, btw

Comment: We're looking at the children of a given control, recursively.  This means we never look up at the parent, instead using the stack to keep track of that lineage.  As a result, it'll work just fine when first control is parentless.

Answer (score 2):

Controls really can only have a single parent.  There isn't really a reason to track "handled", as you'll only execute your method on the control a single time.

Now, if you're using a framework that allows controls to have multiple parents (I'm not aware of any .NET frameworks that allow this), **then** this might be required.  If, however, you're using Windows Forms (which is what this appears to be) or WPF, you can just simplify this to:

```
private static void Traverse(this Control control, Action<Control> action)
{
    foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        Traverse(child, action);
    action(control);
}
```

Comment: In that case, you're going to have other issues.  It's tough to imagine a safe method that's going to be reparenting controls in a method intended to "perform an action on a control and all of its children"

Comment: @Steven: Also,  if you're changing the parenthood, you'll have problems in the foreach, even with "handled" in place...

Comment: Good point.  Changing parents would effectively change the contents of each collection, and that's a foreach no-no.  I guess the only choice would be the usual work-around: iterate once to build a to-do list, then go through and implement the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use recursion

```
public sub DoStuffToControlAndChildren(TargetControl as Control)

    'Insert code to do stuff to TargetControl here

     if TargetControl.Controls.count = 0 then
         return
     end if 

     For each ChildControl in TargetControl.Controls
        DoStuffToControlAndChildren(ChildControl)
     next

end sub
```

Comment: I opted away from recursion by keeping stacks/queues.

Comment: @Daniel: How deep is a tree really going to be?  If the answer is "not very", then recursion will be just fine.

Comment: The answer *is* "not very," but I enjoy the elegance (IMO) of the stacks and queues, and this was both a way to traverse controls as well as an experiment in traversal in general, so I'd like to keep the algorithm as broad as possible. Is there any reason *not* to use stacks and queues? Is the overhead not worth it when you're only traversing a hundred controls nested several deep?

Comment: @Daniel: To be frank, I think that it would work just fine either way.  There are even some general arguments against using recursion in .NET, based on delaying the collection of locals.  In this case, I suspect that recursion will perform at least as well as explicitly allocating a stack, and I feel that it's more elegant.  Clearly, you disagree with the latter. :-)